# Draw Path depending on currently visible views

Tags: swiftui

This is the view I am trying to create:

[image]

Everything except the orange line is in place and working (the green ones are just helper lines for visualisation).

I am trying to retrieve informations on rendered views and set view properties to their rect to calculate the orange `Path`. Right now, this results in the `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` error.

What do I need to change in order to make this work?

Here's my view:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var titleRect: CGRect = .zero
    @State private var dividerRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            VStack {
                Text("Some fancy title …")
                    .border(.green) //
                    .background {
                        GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                            titleRect = proxy.frame(in: .named("root"))
                            return .clear
                        }
                    }
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 20.0)
                    .foregroundColor(.clear)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 1.0)
                    .background {
                        GeometryReader { proxy -> Color in
                            dividerRect = proxy.frame(in: .named("root"))
                            return .clear
                        }
                    }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.top)
            
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: dividerRect.minX, y: titleRect.maxY)) // startingPoint
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: dividerRect.width * 2/3, y: dividerRect.maxY)) // midPoint
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: dividerRect.maxX, y: titleRect.maxY)) // endPoint
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .coordinateSpace(name: "root")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a good workaround for my problem by implementing a `ViewModifier` that can get me the frame size for arbitrary views I need it for:

```swift
struct MeasureSizeModifier: ViewModifier {
    let callback: (CGSize) -> ()
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            callback(proxy.size)
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func measureSize(_ callback: @escaping (CGSize) -> () ) -> some View {
        modifier(MeasureSizeModifier(callback: callback))
    }
}
```

Credits go out to "Flo Writes Code" on YouTube for his tutorial on this: [How to use GeometryReader
BEST in SwiftUl!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2WfptI6HZg&t=3s)

After having implemented what is suggested, I can use this extension like so in my specific case:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var containerWidth: CGFloat = .zero
    @State private var titleHeight: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0)
                .measureSize { size in
                    containerWidth = size.width
                    print(containerWidth)
                }
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
            Text("Some fancy title …")
                .border(.green)
                .measureSize { size in
                    titleHeight = size.height
                }
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: .zero, y: titleHeight))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: containerWidth * 0.67, y: titleHeight * 3))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: containerWidth, y: titleHeight))
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: .zero, y: titleHeight * 3))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: containerWidth, y: titleHeight * 3))
            }
            .stroke(.black)
            .border(.green)
            
            HStack {
                Text("Y")
                Spacer()
                Text("N")
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            .position(x: containerWidth / 2, y: titleHeight * 2)
            .frame(width: containerWidth)
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
}
```

I will have other places where I will be glad to have this extension in my toolbelt